# JOOQ group by nullable column

Tags: java, sql, group-by, nullable, jooq

I have a sql like this:

```
select a.*, count(b.id) from b left join a on b.aid=a.id group by a.id
```

In sql client, I get result like :

```
null  | 100
1     | 20
2     | 30
....
```

but with JOOQ (im using version 3.9.5):

```
dsl.select(..)
 .from(..)
 .leftJoin(..)
 .on(..)
 .groupBy(..)
 .fetchMap(..)
```

the result is a map losing the null key

How can I get the complete result, including the null column with JOOQ?

Comment: You could try using `COALESCE(a.id, 0) AS a_id` and then group by `a_id`

Comment: oops, it's my mistake actually; JOOQ DOES SUPPORT NULLABLE groupBy column and fetchMap!

Comment: If there is no problem you should delete the question